# how to convert this code

Tags: c#

hi i would like to ask if how to convert the Console.WriteLine to Textbox and this the line sorry im just a newbie ....thank you

```
Console.WriteLine("    Status:            {0}", adapters[i].OperationalStatus.ToString())
```

Comment: This question needs work, it doesn't make any sense at the moment.

Comment: `myTextBox.text = adapters[i].OperationalStatus.ToString();`

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean convert Console.WriteLine to a Textbox? If you just want the Textbox to display the text, set the Text property.

```
TextBoxId.Text = String.Format(" Status: {0}", adapters[i].OperationalStatus.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
Your_TextBox.Text = String.Format("Status:{0}",
    adapters[i].OperationalStatus.ToString())
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
TextBox.Text = String.Format("    Status:      {0}", adapters[i].OperationalStatus.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using `String.Format` as much as @Brandon and @Neil Knight do, but here's an alternative (not necessarily a better one):

```
myTextBox.Text = "    Status:      " + adapters[i].OperationalStatus.ToString();
```